# How to get access Cloud Foundry App instances?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have an application deployed and scaled horizontally (let's assume 5 of them) in the Cloud Foundry. I have rest endpoint in the application to update some internal resources.

I want to call that endpoint for each of instances in some intervals.
Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can target a specific instances by setting the `X-CF-APP-INSTANCE` header in your request. The format of the header is `X-CF-APP-INSTANCE: APP_GUID:APP_INDEX`.

See the docs here for more details.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#-routing-requests-to-a-specific-app-instance

Do keep in mind that there are no guarantees that an individual app instance will exist when you send the request, and if it doesn't your request will fail with a 404.

Also note that the index is a zero based number where zero is the first instance, one is the second instance, etc.